# Terminal commands, where does the cpu temperature difference come from?

Tags: macos, terminal, hardware, temperature

What's the correct way to get current CPU temperature? And why different programs return different CPU temperatures, for example, one command returns 70C, the other 52C

```
sudo powermetrics -i 200 --samplers smc | grep 'CPU die'
```

and

```
brew install osx-cpu-temp
osx-cpu-temp
```

To stress test CPUs:

```
stress --cpu 4 --timeout 60
```

Comment: Both tools get the temperature from the SMC, actually. If you run tests over a longer time, do the figures keep being different

Comment: I was using this implementation for my App: https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp/blob/master/smc.c
I don't really care about averages over long period of times. All i want is to get current temperature sensor information and to display it to the user.  This implementation gives similar results to "osx-cpu-temp". However, it seems that it does not increase the temperature when stress testing CPU and I'm not sure that it returns correct temperature.

Comment: osx-cpu-temp returns a result instantly, and powermetrics works indefinitely until stopped. Both commands show different results when executed at the same time.

Comment: So they're reading different sensors?

Comment: Yes, you're right, one is reading "CPU 0 Proximity temp" sensor, the other is reading "CPU 0 die temp" sensor. Ok, i'm having another problem, changing sensor to "CPU 0 die temp" fails to read in smc.c implementation. My following question would be why, but i feel like this deserves another topic. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Turns out different devices have different sensors, and sensor codes differ on each device https://logi.wiki/index.php/SMC_Sensor_Codes This is far more complicated than i thought.